# Using google address api to search for business

Tags: html, google-maps-api-3, google-api, street-address

I have created the following example below on a storefront so clients can search for their address and have it autofill each input.

[Google Api example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform)

Most of our clients are businesses so I would like to make it so you can search a business and it will return the address. Is this possible with the Google Address API?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with the Google Places API (which is what the example you link to uses). Are you looking for just businesses?  Or the addition of businesses to the existing form?

Comment: Addition of businesses to the existing form @geocodezip. Right now for example I can not search for a local restaurant close by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified the [example in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform) to remove the limitation on addresses (removed the `{types: ['geocode']}`), added the "name" to the form.

```js
// This example displays an address form, using the autocomplete feature
// of the Google Places API to help users fill in the information.

var placeSearch, autocomplete;
var componentForm = {
  street_number: 'short_name',
  route: 'long_name',
  locality: 'long_name',
  administrative_area_level_1: 'short_name',
  country: 'long_name',
  postal_code: 'short_name'
};

function initAutocomplete() {
  // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search to geographical
  // location types.
  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */
    (document.getElementById('autocomplete')));

  // When the user selects an address from the dropdown, populate the address
  // fields in the form.
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', fillInAddress);
}

// [START region_fillform]
function fillInAddress() {
    // Get the place details from the autocomplete object.
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (place.name) {
      document.getElementById("businessName").value = place.name;
      document.getElementById("businessName").disabled = false;
    }
    for (var component in componentForm) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = '';
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    // Get each component of the address from the place details
    // and fill the corresponding field on the form.
    for (var i = 0; i < place.address_components.length; i++) {
      var addressType = place.address_components[i].types[0];
      if (componentForm[addressType]) {
        var val = place.address_components[i][componentForm[addressType]];
        document.getElementById(addressType).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
  // [END region_fillform]

// [START region_geolocation]
// Bias the autocomplete object to the user's geographical location,
// as supplied by the browser's 'navigator.geolocation' object.
function geolocate() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = {
          lat: position.coords.latitude,
          lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
          center: geolocation,
          radius: position.coords.accuracy
        });
        autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
      });
    }
  }
  // [END region_geolocation]
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initAutocomplete)
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places"></script>
<div id="locationField">
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text" />
</div>

<table id="address">
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Name</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="businessName" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Street address</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="street_number" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="2">
      <input class="field" id="route" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">City</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="locality" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">State</td>
    <td class="slimField">
      <input class="field" id="administrative_area_level_1" disabled="true" />
    </td>
    <td class="label">Zip code</td>
    <td class="wideField">
      <input class="field" id="postal_code" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="label">Country</td>
    <td class="wideField" colspan="3">
      <input class="field" id="country" disabled="true" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```